# Function Help Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x

```
def areaOfRectangle (length,width):
area = length*width
sqArea = length**2
return area,sqArea


def areaOfSquare (length,):
areaOfRectangle (length,width)
return sqArea

#def radiusOfCircle (radius):
area = 3.14*(radius**2)
return area

#def volumeOfCylinder (radius,height):
volume = 3.14*(radius**2)*height
return volume

length = int(input("Input length: "))
width = int(input("Input width: "))
print()
print(areaOfRectangle (10,20))
print()
print(areaOfRectangle (24.3,6))
print()
print(areaOfRectangle (34.9,17.4))
print()
print(areaOfRectangle (length,width))
print()
print(areaOfSquare (10.3))
```

I need to make two functions, the first function to calculate the area of a rectangle given the length and width. The second function needs to calculate the area of a square given the length of one of its sides. The second function should call the previous function to perform the calculation. I know how to call a function within another function however I don't know how to bring a variable from the first function to the second.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to bring a variable from the first function to the second

Typically, this is done through the use of parameters. Let's say you have a value `x`:

```
x = 0
```

You can pass the value to a function by inserting it into the call itself:

```
f(x)
```

Lastly, the function needs to be able to handle the parameter you give it:

```
def f(y): pass
```

A working example of what you describe:

```
def f2(y):
    return y + 1
def f1():
    x = 2
    print(f2(x))
f1()
```

`3` is printed.